# Way to click on visible elements of all the enabled elements

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, fluentlenium

Is there a way to click on only the visible of all the returned elements using Fluentlenium(similar to selenium)???
For example I have

```
@FindBy(css = "div[class^='event-body']>button")
    public FluentWebElement hostMeeting;
```

This will return may buttons. Of all only one will be visible.
I want to click on that.

Comment: Then you need to target the visible element with a better locator, surely?

Comment: in selenium we have the method element.isDisplayed() which can be used in your case.

Comment: @Arran AFAIK, there's no better locator, since the only thing unique is another button, which is child element of parent element of this element.

Comment: @lost That's not working, I don't know why

Comment: Perhaps share the HTML so we can see how these two buttons actually relate to each other.

Comment: Well surely you are clicking on the overall "ClickThisMeeting" element to *expand* it *first* right?

Comment: Yeah, I am clicking on that element before clicking on start meeting button

Answer (score 0):

The goal here is to find how it hides the elements.  Usually, this would be the inline style attribute.  It would be something like:

```
<div class="event-body something">
  <button style="display: none;" />
  ...
</div>
```

You'd match it by editing your CSS selector:

```
div.event-body > button:not([style*='display:none'])
```

Comment: <button class="host-meeting" rel="/644299000/1125/"> this is the element.
Every other element is similar

Comment: so if the class `host-meeting` is causing it, (you can test that by removing it via console.)  then change my selector to be `class~='host-meeting'`

Comment: the element which i want to click also belong to the same class.
They are differed only by rel(which will change every time) and visibilty